Microphone detected and test bar shows pickup, but apps won't record
I'm using Windows 10 Pro 22H2. I have a Earphones+Mic combination connected via USB. They are detected; and if I go to Settings > Sound > Input, I see this mic as an input device, and the "Test your microphone" bar shows pickup when I speak into the mic.
In "Microphone Privacy Settings", I've set "Allow apps to use your microphone" and "Allow desktop apps to use your microphone". I've also specifically toggled "Voice Recorder" on.
However, when I use the Voice Record app, and when I use Teams on my browser (Edge) - despite the device being mentioned and not marked as mute, no audio is picked up and recorded.
How can I make these (and other) apps pick up audio from my mic?

Most recording and conferencing applications have a setting to select the input device.
Perhaps the default is the PC's internal microphone, or the mic input jack. If that is the case, the headset mic must be selected, instead.
Apparently, for Teams, you must select the audio input device when joining. However, there appears to be a known issue for setting the headset as default device: "My headset will appear in device options in Teams and I have to re-select it there in order to use it in -teams again... Teams will not automatically default back to my headset... Teams only defaults back if every other sound option is disabled from the sound control panel."
Hopefully, that will solve the issue for Teams, and perhaps for the MS Sound Recorder.

Interesting. I'll try that next time.
